# Dynamic table row display on ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a table with 50 rows and want display initially only 10. Just below the table we'd like to add a "Show all" link (not a button) that allow, dynamically (or after reloading the page), to display of all the 50 rows.

What is the most straightforward way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: without the use of a component?

Comment: Possibly yes, what component do you have in mind?

Comment: you can use table sorter

Comment: I think it is interesting jqgrid. http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a model composed of an `int` and a `List<DataRow>`:

```
public class MyDisplayViewModel
{
     public int FullCount { get; set; }
     public List<DataRow> Data { get; set; }
}
```

When populating your `Data` object (in your controller, for example) you can take the full count of your existing data and pass it in the `FullCount` property.

```
public ActionResult GetData(int count)
{
     MyDisplayViewModel model = new MyDisplayViewModel();

     //pseudocode for getting the total number of records
     model.FullCount = yourDataProvider(yourDataType).Count();

     //pseudocode for getting the the list of records
     model.Data = yourDataProvider(yourDataType, count);

     return View(model);
}
```

You can check then in your view if the data passed to it corresponds to all the "available" data. If not, show the link to get all the data from your database.

```
@{
     foreach(var row in Model.Data)
     {
          //display your data
     }

     if (Model.Data.Count != Model.FullCount)
     {
         @Html.ActionLink("Load all", "GetData", "YourControllerName", 
                 new { count = Model.FullCount }, null)
     }
}
```

Of course, this suggestion is at the conceptual level. the view, for example, can implement an Ajax request, in order to get *only the remaining `DataRow`s*.